# About the EX1-9 of K&R

Tags: c, getchar

Here's the text of Exercise 1-9 from the book 'The C programming language' by Ritchie&Kernighan:

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

To me the simplest way of solving that problem is writing

```
int single_byte = getchar();

while (single_byte != EOF) {
  putchar(single_byte);
  if (single_byte == ' ')
    while ((single_byte = getchar()) == ' ')
      ;
  else
    single_byte = getchar();
}
```

though I was told (last night in the #c channel of *irc.freenode.net*) it would be more readable getting rid of the nested `while` by implementing a comparison between the last character saved and the one just read. What I thought is kind of this:

```
int current_byte = getchar();

if (current_byte == EOF)
  return 1;

putchar(current_byte);
int previous_byte = current_byte;

while ((current_byte = getchar()) != EOF) {
  if (current_byte == ' ' && previous_byte == ' ')
    ;
  else
    putchar(current_byte);

previous_byte = current_byte;
}
```

that does not satisfy me at all: starting from the first `if`-statement (for the case when there's nothing to read).
Additionally I wish I could push the last two lines before the `while` inside the loop; the less I should distinguish the beginning from the rest of the execution, the happier I am !

Comment: What is your question, giuscri?

Comment: If anyone has some other idea for getting rid of the nested `while` (in the first piece of code) and if not how can I push more lines inside the loop (in the second piece of code).

Comment: Sounds to me like you should just move on to the next exercise, but here's a [bunch of solutions easily googleable](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_9).

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I'll do that very quickly, though I'd like to hear other opinions. =)

Comment: You can also use a flag which you set as 1 as long as you encounter the first space. Then again set it to 0 when you get a character other than space.

Comment: Readability is pretty subjective, this seems like an off-topic question for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program doesn't need multiple loops statements or any else statements.

This seems like a straight-forward way to solve the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int single_byte;
    int last_char;
    for(last_char = 0; (single_byte = getchar()) != EOF; last_char = single_byte)
    {
        if(last_char != ' ' || single_byte != ' ')
            putchar(single_byte);
    }
}
```

Comment: uhm ...don't really like that `last_char` is initialized to `0` (it is a character chosen randomly) though maybe that is kinda what I was looking for.